When to use the `AddEnumerateCounter` in enumitem?
I want a custom itemize style of counter as below:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\definecolor{sintefblue}{RGB}{38, 113, 142}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*\itemlabel[1]{
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=rectangle,fill=sintefblue,rounded corners=2pt,inner sep=2pt, minimum size=12pt] (char) {\color{white} {#1}};}
}
% \AddEnumerateCounter{\mycnt}{\itemlabel}{2}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\itemlabel{\arabic*}]
        \item Step one
        \item Step two
        \item Step three
    \end{enumerate}% Good
    % \begin{enumerate}[label=\mycnt*]
    %     \item Step one
    %     \item Step two
    %     \item Step three
    % \end{enumerate}%Failed
\end{document}

And I know that the macro \AddEnumerateCounter is used to regester a counter representation so that enumitem recognizes it. Th syntax is \AddEnumerateCounter{<LaTeX command>}{<internal command>}{<widest label>}, the <internal command> is a command which gobble one paramater and output the custom style, like the example in the documentation:
\makeatletter
\def\ctext#1{\expandafter\@ctext\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@ctext#1{\ifcase#1\or First\or Second\or Third\or
Fourth\or Fifth\or Sixth\fi}
\makeatother
\AddEnumerateCounter{\ctext}{\@ctext}{Second}

But how can I use \AddEnumerateCounter in my case of \itemlabel with the MWE above?

You're misusing \AddEnumerateCounter.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\definecolor{sintefblue}{RGB}{38, 113, 142}

\tikzset{
  itemlabel/.style={
    shape=rectangle,
    fill=sintefblue,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    inner sep=2pt,
    minimum size=12pt,
  },
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemlabel}{m}{% <--- don't forget
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[itemlabel] (char) {\color{white} {#1}};}% <--- don't forget
}

\newcommand{\mycnt}[1]{\itemlabel{\arabic{#1}}}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\mycnt}{\itemlabel}{2}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\itemlabel{\arabic*}]
  \item Step one
  \item Step two
  \item Step three
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\mycnt*]
  \item Step one
  \item Step two
  \item Step three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

Using a style makes the definition of \itemlabel more readable. You may want to add ref= if you plan to use labels to the items.

You should use \newcommand for \mycnt (or \NewExpandableDocumentCommand) or the expansion needed in the .aux file cannot take place.

Oh, yes, what stuck me is where to use \arabic* to let \itemlabel know its parameter. And I misunderstood the \AddEnumerateCounter and think that it define the <LaTeX command> without thinking more with the example. Thanks a lot!
